# why cant i access my django website on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-hosting

```
2020-12-07T09:11:23.229280+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-12-07T09:11:23.229280+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-07T09:11:23.229284+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'STOCK'
2020-12-07T09:11:23.229493+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-07 09:11:23 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2020-12-07T09:11:23.312182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-12-07T09:11:23.354768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-07T09:11:26.483885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stockwares.herokuapp.com request_id=886eaa6b-6294-49e8-a765-634918f2e93b fwd="223.236.7.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-07T09:11:28.426668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockwares.herokuapp.com request_id=f89b8ecb-bbc3-4004-93a3-63dd230a3b73 fwd="223.236.7.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-07T09:12:41.759328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=stockwares.herokuapp.com request_id=ab605bed-037f-4f76-b3b9-bccf30882066 fwd="223.236.7.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-07T09:12:42.571231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stockwares.herokuapp.com request_id=ab5dfcf0-beeb-4f3b-b65e-1ba34acde43c fwd="223.236.7.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Comment: You've tried to import a python module named `STOCK` which doesn't exist so your app won't run.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show us more of that error message. And please show us your directory structure, your `Procfile`, and whatever file is triggering that error.

Comment: if STOCK didnt exist it would also not run on my localhost right?but its running @markwalker_

Comment: @Rayyan i dont know the format to add STOCK to installed apps please let me know,also its owrking on my localhost.

Comment: @Chris i cant add things to my question because stackoverflow is giving me an error saying code should be sectioned or something.

Comment: "i cant add things to my question because stackoverflow is giving me an error saying code should be sectioned or something"—please don't paraphrase error messages. What, _exactly_, is the error that you are seeing? See [ask].

Comment: @ShubhamJain I was confusing myself as I am a beginner. I am not sure what the problem is. Can you add more things to your question as Chris stated?